# Regex help for this expression with digits wanted

Tags: c#, regex

I am splitting given text wherever  `eachDELETEDDELETED` occours, however some of my files contain text like:

```
each2,DELETED6,DELETED
eachDELETED2,DELETED
each5,DELETED15,DELETED
each5,DELETED5,DELETED2
```

I want to do a regex replace and turn these expressions into `eachDELETEDDELETED`.

I have tried using the follow code:

```
Regex ra = new Regex(@"eachDELETED\d, DELETED");

MatchCollection mcMatches = ra.Matches(extracted);

foreach (Match m in mcMatches)
{
    if (m.Success)
    {
        //  MessageBox.Show(m.Value.ToString());
        richTextBox5.Text += "JJJJ------>" +m.Value + "\n";
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting any matches.

Comment: Capture digits or a comma, delete these and you should be fine: [`([\d,]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/wY6zB3/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `each\d*,*DELETED\d*,DELETED\d*` matches all the sample data:

> each2,DELETED6,DELETED
>   eachDELETED2,DELETED
>   each5,DELETED15,DELETED
>   each5,DELETED5,DELETED2

If the lack of the comma in the second line is a typo, use `each\d*,DELETED\d*,DELETED\d*`

Basically, `\d` matches a digit and `*` means zero or more times.

Comment: I guess this is not what OP was after.

Comment: @Jan the DV can't be from the OP as you can't DV until 125 rep, so I'll leave it here until they comment, or the DV reveals themselves.